# remove duplicate values from a list with multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public DateTime? DueDate;
    public string Desc;
    public Decimal Amount;
}

var sample = new List<MyClass>();
```

This is how sample data looks like :

```
DueDate     Desc    Amount 
06-29-2015  ABC     100
06-29-2015  DEF     200
01-15-2015  ABC     100
01-15-2015  DEF     200
```

Output I want in this format

```
DueDate     Desc    Amount 
06-29-2015  ABC     100
            DEF     200
01-15-2015  ABC     100
            DEF     200
```

So basically I would like to **remove duplicate `DueDate` values** but keeping its adjacent `Desc` & `Amount` field values

I tried this but it will remove values from adjacent column as well :

```
var test = sample.GroupBy(d => d.DueDate).Select(a => a.First()).ToList();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define what you mean by "adjacent". Is this adjacent within the original ordering of `sample`, or adjacent after the `GroupBy`? If `GroupBy`, note that this will potentially output in a different order than `sample`.

Comment: @budi : By "adjacent" I meant delete duplicate values from `DueDate` column but not from `Desc` & `Amount` column in the same row.

Comment: Define "delete", like delete completely from the object? And what if the data dates are in this order: `[06-29-2015, 01-15-2015, 06-29-2015]`

Comment: Also, do you want your output to be just a string or do you need it in another data structure?

Comment: Yes. Delete completely from the object. In that case, delete 2nd most duplicate item. Though my list would be sorted by `DueDate` so order does not matter!

Comment: @maccettura: It has to be same data structure as the input one.

Comment: OK well your `DueDate` property is not nullable, so you wont be able to "remove" the DueDate from subsequent items in the "group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to "remove" (set to `null`) duplicate, adjacent `DueDate`s from the `sample` list:

```
sample.GroupBy(d => d.DueDate).ToList()
    .ForEach(g => g.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(o => o.DueDate = null));
```

This is done by `Group`-ing by `DueDate`, and for each group, `Skip`-ing the first element, setting the remainder of the elements in the group `DueDate`s to `null`.

---

Output with format:

```
Console.WriteLine("DueDate     Desc    Amount");
foreach (var item in sample)
{
    var dateString = item.DueDate != null
        ? item.DueDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
        : string.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine(dateString.PadRight(12) + item.Desc + "     " + item.Amount);
}
```

---

Result:

```
DueDate     Desc    Amount
06-29-2015  ABC     100
            DEF     200
01-15-2015  ABC     100
            DEF     200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalData = data
    .GroupBy(d=>d.DueDate)
    .Select(g=>
        new {
            DueDate = g.Key, 
            Values = g.Select(d2=>new{d2.Desc, d2.Amount})})
```

The Final Structure would be

```
finalDate = [
    {
        DueDate:'06-29-1015', 
        Values:[{Desc:"ABC", Amount:100}, {Desc:"DEF", Amount:200}]
    },
    {...}
]
```

**EDIT:-**

```
var finalData = data
        .GroupBy(d=>d.DueDate)
        .Select(g=>
            new {
                 DueDate = g.Key, 
                 Values = g.Select(d2=>d2)
                })
        .ToDictionary(o=>o.DueDate, o=>o.Values)
```

Comment: This solution you take OP's nice strongly typed classes and turn them into anonymous types though.

Comment: @maccettura - i have edited my answer to remove the anonymous types

Comment: Wasn't me, I think one of the other posters wants to make their answer seem better by comparison.

Comment: Wasn't me either, looks like everyone got downvoted. However, I'm curious why all the answers assumed that order does not need to be preserved.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your latest comments I have edited my answer.

As I am understanding, your requirements are:

- Group by DueDate, and only allow the first of the group to have a
  DueDate.
- The results **have** to be the same structure.

If you want to **remove** the `DueDate` property from all `i>0` items in a group then you need to make your property nullable: `public DateTime? DueDate;`.  This way you can assign the value of null to subsequent items in the group.

```
//New list to hold our new items
var outputList = new List<MyClass>();       

//Groups all the items together by DueDate
foreach(var grouping in samples.GroupBy(d => d.DueDate))
{       
    //Iterates through all items in a group (selecting the index as well)
    foreach(var item in grouping.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }))
    {
        //If this is any item after the first one, we remove the due date
        if(item.Index > 0)
        {
            item.Value.DueDate = null;
        }
        outputList.Add(item.Value);
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/On9HA3).

Comment: Well, that includes two loops, grouping, selecting and anonymous types. Quite a bit overkilly, I think?

Comment: @Waescher as I said in my comment, its clunky to get the "table" view the OP showed in their code (to illustrate exactly what they asked for).  Thats why my answer **does not include** that code.  The core of my answer was excluding the `Select(x => x.First()` which is exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply prefer that you loop through your records after you got them in the correct order. Just start with an empty variable and keep the last date in it. If the next value is the same, just don't plot it out. If you find another date value the next iteration, plot it and overwrite your variable for further iterations.

Yeah I know, Linq and Lambdas are cool and stuff (and I love them too) but in this case it seems to be appropriate to me.

```
    var last = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (var f in sample.OrderBy(x => x.DueDate))
    {
        if (f.DueDate.Equals(last))
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", "SKIP DATE", f.Desc, f.Amount);
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", f.DueDate.ToShortDateString(), f.Desc, f.Amount);
            last = f.DueDate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the down vote? It works, it's blazingly fast and your colleagues will instantly be able to read it. What's the matter of a 5-line-rocketscience-lambda if you need 4 additional comment lines to explain it for others or for yourself if you head back two days later?

Comment: I think most people would prefer a simple `GroupBy()` instead of this.

Comment: Yeah, but just doing some grouping won't be enough. You will still have a loop afterwards and even anonymous types and stuff. Well, one could do that ...

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a pivot table.  this is how it is done :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.Load();
            myClass.CreatePivotTable();

        }
    }
    class MyClass
    {
        public static List<MyClass> samples = new List<MyClass>();

        public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public Decimal amount { get; set; }

        public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public void Load()
        {
            samples = new List<MyClass>() {
                new MyClass() { dueDate = DateTime.Parse("06-29-2015"), desc = "ABC", amount = 100},
                new MyClass() { dueDate = DateTime.Parse("06-29-2015"), desc = "DEF", amount = 200},
                new MyClass() { dueDate = DateTime.Parse("01-15-2015"), desc = "ABC", amount = 100},
                new MyClass() { dueDate = DateTime.Parse("01-15-2015"), desc = "DEF", amount = 100}
            };

        }
        public void CreatePivotTable()
        {
            string[] uniqueDescription = samples.Select(x => x.desc).Distinct().ToArray();

            dt.Columns.Add("Due Date", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach (string desc in uniqueDescription)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(desc, typeof(decimal));
            }

            var groups = samples.GroupBy(x => x.dueDate);

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Due Date"] = group.Key;

                foreach (string col in uniqueDescription)
                {
                    newRow[col] = group.Where(x => x.desc == col).Sum(x => x.amount);
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```